# Can a cube be cut according to these rules?

Tags: recurrence-relations, volume, solid-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I'm reading [Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/concrete-mathematics-a/9780134389974/) (for my own amusement), and after working out the recurrence for the number of three-dimensional regions that can be defined by $n$ different planes, I got interested in another question, more geometrical than combinatoric in nature, which I have no idea how to begin solving.

---

The recurrence mentioned:

Given some regular three-dimensional figure such as a cube, the number of pieces $P_n$ it may be cut into by $n$ slices (planes) satisfies the following recurrence (spoilered because it is a *great* problem to work out yourself):

> $$P_n=P_{n-1}+L_{n-1}$$
>  $$L_n=L_{n-1}+n$$
>  $$P_0=1$$
>  $$L_0=1$$

($L_n$ as defined above is the maximal number of two dimensional regions that may be formed on a plane by $n$ lines.)

---

$P_4=15$, so for instance it is possible to cut a large cube of cheese into 15 pieces using 4 slices.

My question:

**Is it possible to cut a cube into $15$ pieces *of equal volume* using $4$ straight cuts?**

How can I go about solving this?  Other than getting a large lump of clay and a knife to experiment with and observe, is there any geometric method that would allow me to work out the necessary cuts and prove they are correct?

A follow up question of interest: it is obviously not possible to have all 15 pieces the same *shape* (though with $3$ cuts it is trivially easy to make $P_3=8$ identical pieces).  However, is it possible to have 2 or more of the 15 pieces identical?  And inversely, is it possible to have *no* pieces identical (but all have the same volume)?

---

If it is possible, is this possible for all $n$?  In other words, for any $n \ge 0$, is it possible to cut a cube into $P_n$ pieces *of equal volume*?

Comment: I suppose I should really start by trying to cut a square into $7$ pieces of equal area using $3$ straight lines, and see if that's possible.  I hadn't thought of that before actually writing the question out, though.

Comment: Forgive me, but what is the purpose of $L$? With your current definition $L_n = n+1$. Is this a mistake or on purpose?

Comment: @orlp, oops!  Fixing.